# when installing mono getting various errors?

Tags: mono, ubuntu-12.04, monodevelop

requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help resolve the situation:

I have installed mono.But later when trying to install xsp4 accidentally gave for the removal of some files. After that am not able to install anything. What ever i try to install it is saying this depends on that that depends on this. Please help.

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mono-devel : Depends: libmono-system-runtime4.0-cil (>= 2.10.1) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libmono-system-servicemodel4.0a-cil (>= 3.2.3) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libmono-system-web-services4.0-cil (>= 1.0) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libmono-system-web2.0-cil (>= 2.10.3) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libmono2.0-cil (>= 3.6.0) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libmono-cil-dev (= 3.10.0-0xamarin2) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
I tried the following had happened

Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgtk2.0-cil : Depends: libcairo2 (>= 1.12.0) but 1.10.2-6.1ubuntu3 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
root@saasbook:~/monodevelop# apt-get install libcairo2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
libcairo2 is already the newest version.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libmono-web4.0-cil libglade2-0 libmono-opensystem-c4.0-cil mono-dmcs
  libwebkitgtk-1.0-common libwebkitgtk-1.0-0 libjavascriptcoregtk-1.0-0
  mono-gmcs
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 364 not upgraded.
root@saasbook:~/monodevelop# ^C
root@saasbook:~/monodevelop#

eventhough I have libcairo2 it is saying not found.. what can i do?

Comment: Any chance you solved this? I spent way too much time trying to figure this out yesterday.

Comment: i would suggest uninstall whole mono package including mono develop and install a fresh copy. I also faced the same situation.. tried for 2 days.But couldn't resolve all the unmet dependencies.I installed a fresh copy then it started working fine.